# Mapbox missing Gl JS css

Tags: html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

My map is not loading and no error is being displayed in the console.
please help.
this is the error screenshot as [shown in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0qP4.png)
 there is no build error while compiling the code neither any error is thrown but the ma form mabox is not loading and is written as - Missing mapbox Gl JS CSS

the following is the code snippet for the same

```js
// code for map.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { MapService } from '../map.service';
import { GeoJson, FeatureCollection } from '../map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-box',
  templateUrl: './map-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-box.component.css']
})
export class MapBoxComponent implements OnInit{

  /// default settings
  map: mapboxgl.Map;
  style = 'mapbox://styles/kanavmalik10/cjfbjx6fp70fl2snuphc7zjw2';
  lat = 37.75;
  lng = -122.41;
  message = 'Hello World!';

  // data
  source: any;
  markers: any;

  constructor(private mapService: MapService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.markers = this.mapService.getMarkers()
    this.initializeMap()
  }

  private initializeMap() {
    /// locate the user
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.map.flyTo({
          center: [this.lng, this.lat]
        })
      });
    }

    this.buildMap()

  }

  buildMap() {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: this.style,
      zoom: 13,
      center: [this.lng, this.lat]
    });


    /// Add map controls
    this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());


    //// Add Marker on Click
    this.map.on('click', (event) => {
      const coordinates = [event.lngLat.lng, event.lngLat.lat]
      const newMarker   = new GeoJson(coordinates, { message: this.message })
      this.mapService.createMarker(newMarker)
    })


    /// Add realtime firebase data on map load
    this.map.on('load', (event) => {

      /// register source
      this.map.addSource('firebase', {
         type: 'geojson',
         data: {
           type: 'FeatureCollection',
           features: []
         }
      });

      /// get source
      this.source = this.map.getSource('firebase')

      /// subscribe to realtime database and set data source
      this.markers.subscribe(markers => {
          let data = new FeatureCollection(markers)
          this.source.setData(data)
      })

      /// create map layers with realtime data
      this.map.addLayer({
        id: 'firebase',
        source: 'firebase',
        type: 'symbol',
        layout: {
          'text-field': '{message}',
          'text-size': 24,
          'text-transform': 'uppercase',
          'icon-image': 'rocket-15',
          'text-offset': [0, 1.5]
        },
        paint: {
          'text-color': '#f16624',
          'text-halo-color': '#fff',
          'text-halo-width': 2
        }
      })

    })

  }


  /// Helpers

  removeMarker(marker) {
    this.mapService.removeMarker(marker.$key)
  }

  flyTo(data: GeoJson) {
    this.map.flyTo({
      center: data.geometry.coordinates
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="your message...">
<h1>Markers</h1>
<div *ngFor="let marker of markers | async">
  <button (click)="flyTo(marker)">{{ marker.properties.message }}</button>
  <button (click)="removeMarker(marker)">Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="map" id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seed to include the GL JS CSS stylesheet. See the quickstart at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/overview/#quickstart

```
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Comment: I had already included this file in my index.html page rather now the map is showing when I hide the link ref, do tell me if you need to see image for that ill send it to you

Comment: It could be some other part of your app is interfering? I see some CSS from Mapbox is working, like the attribution and logo.